# nested edit path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to figure out the edit path within `_comment.html.erb` file.

Keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#edit
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fcac37359e8>
```

Don't know how to figure how to write the correct path.

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit 
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end


  def destroy 
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy 
    redirect_to article_path(@article) 
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article.comments, comment) %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Show', [comment.article, comment] %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

**routes**

```
  resources :articles do 
    resources :comments
  end
```

How do I write the correct path?

Also, the earlier path I had was this:

```
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
```

But it would turn up a blank edit form, ie, none of the text boxes had anything filled in ... hence why I tried the other path.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Comment _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Article show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Comment: Ya, you're second example is more accurate.  Your initial error is stating you're passing an array of objects when it expects a single object.  Can I see the code you use to render your partial ?

Comment: @Anthony, sorry, not completely sure what you mean ... I mean, I know what you mean but ... anyway, have also included the Article's show file ... that's the one that renders the comments ... let me know if you meant otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in **_comment.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article.comments, comment) %>
```

It should be

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
```

> But it would turn up a blank edit form, ie, none of the text boxes had anything filled in

You should check if you are passing the proper values in `form_for`

```
<%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>
```

**EDIT2**

Well the problem is you are passing new instance of comment every time, Even with the edit action. That's why you are not getting any values in the form

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

And make sure you are assigning `@article` and `@comment` in both `new` and `edit` action of `CommentsController` or from wherever you are rendering the `comments/_form`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.new
  end

  def edit 
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  #...
end
```

Comment: have updated my post with the Comment's `_form.html.erb` ... I tried yours right now, and I got this error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` in reference to your line ... any ideas? Thank you!